# How to do setstate that depends on multiple futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, flutter-futurebuilder

I am making a group buying app, which will show list of nearest deal, newest deal, and ending soon deal. If these 3 lists are empty, I want to show a button for user to add a deal. But I encountered "setState called during Build" error.
Here is what I have tried:

```dart
int listCount = 0;
bool hasNearest = false;
bool hasNewest = false;
bool hasEnding = false;
bool showButton = false;

void checkState(int count, String mode) {
  listCount = listCount + count;
  if (mode == 'nearest') hasNearest = true;
  if (mode == 'newest') hasNewest = true;
  if (mode == 'ending') hasEnding = true;

  if (hasNearest && hasNewest && hasEnding && listCount <= 0) {
    setState((){
      showButton = true;
    })
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      // for nearest deal
      FutureBuilder(
        future: getNearestDealMethod(), // method from other helper class, returning future object
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<Deal> list = snapshot.data;
                checkState(list.length, 'nearest');

                if (list.length > 0) { // show deal widget }
              } else {
                return Text("No Deal");
              }
              break;

            default:
              return Text("Error");
          }
        }
      ),
      // for newest deal
      FutureBuilder(
        future: getNewestDealMethod(), // method from other helper class, returning future object
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<Deal> list = snapshot.data;
                checkState(list.length, 'newest');

                if (list.length > 0) { // show deal widget }
              } else {
                return Text("No Deal");
              }
              break;

            default:
              return Text("Error");
          }
        }
      ),
      // for ending deal
      FutureBuilder(
        future: getEndingDealMethod(), // method from other helper class, returning future object
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<Deal> list = snapshot.data;
                checkState(list.length, 'ending');

                if (list.length > 0) { // show deal widget }
              } else {
                return Text("No Deal");
              }
              break;

            default:
              return Text("Error");
          }
        }
      ),
      if (showButton) ...[
        Text('show button here')
      ]
    ]
  );
}
```

I'm not using a provider to store fetch data, because the client insisted that every time this page is load, app must retrieve the latest value from cloud.

What should I do to make this work? Or is my approach incorrect here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a future builder set state will rebuild the ui and call the future again. An option to fix this is to extract the widget to a new class and perform set state in the extracted widget.. or you can consider using some state management libraries like bloc or river pod

Comment: Do you mean I should extract the future builder into a separate class? Or the `Text('show button here')` ? If I'm using state management, does it mean I have to create 3 separate state for each list? Sorry, I'm still new in flutter.

Comment: Create new class that will take a bool  and return a widget. So when you update the bool it will return a button or nothing. In this exaple the text show button

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass future function directly just pass the instance of future builder like

```
Future<List<....>>?futureFile ;

@override void initState() {
 super.initState();
 futureFile = getNearestDealMethod();
 }

 FutureBuilder(
    future: futureFile, // method from other helper class, returning 
 futurobject
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
     .....
```

Comment: Do you mean I should create 3 futureFile, for each list? If I put those in initState(), will it be triggered every time the page is accessed? Sorry, I'm still new in flutter.

Comment: When you pass the instance the future task is called only single time and every setstate method called after doesn't restart the future task because inside future builder we donot call a future task with every build method called . when you want to call the future simply do
=> setState(()  {
futureFile = getNearestDealMethod();}) to rebuild your UI. and

Comment: and may be this code go inside build context with out setstate on it 
if (hasNearest && hasNewest && hasEnding && listCount <= 0) {
    setState((){
      showButton = true;
    })
  }
}